# When are profiles between Meta and Travel synchronized/updated?

Tags: discussion, support

I just recieved the `Yearling` badge two times on my travel.meta-profile in about 30 minutes. Since I joined travel.stackexchange about 2 years ago and I do have over 200 reputation, this is not the issue here. I just wondered why I get two "year related" badges during 30 minutes and why I get them now, after having them earned on travel SE a year (first) and 2 weeks (second) ago.

Also, I recieved the `Autobiographer` badge as well, while I completed my profile on travel SE in 2015 and thus earned the badge there.

So, I guess my real question is: When are profiles between travel.meta SE and travel SE synchronized/updated? I don't remember visiting travel.meta before I saw the notification of the earned `Yearling` badge in the notification area.

Comment: The yearling badge can, as you noticed, be awarded multiple times. Looking at my own profile I seem to have been awarded it almost simultaneously in the network site and meta site for the other two sites I am on. That does not completely answer your question which is why I am only posting this as a comment.

Comment: Badge syncs are slow and messy.